# How do I open a TCP socket from SilverLight?

Tags: silverlight, tcp, sockets

I need to know how to open a TCP socket connection from Silverlight. How is it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google search delivers this site

[Silverlight 2 and System.Net.Sockets.Socket](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-and-sockets.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace SilverlightSocketClient
{
    public partial class Page : UserControl
    {
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += PageLoaded;     
        }

        void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var endPoint = new DnsEndPoint(Application.Current.Host.Source.DnsSafeHost, 4530);
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs {UserToken = socket, RemoteEndPoint = endPoint};

            args.Completed += OnSocketConnectCompleted;
            socket.ConnectAsync(args);   
        }

        private void OnSocketConnectCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            var response = new byte[1024];
            e.SetBuffer(response, 0, response.Length);
            e.Completed -= OnSocketConnectCompleted;
            e.Completed += OnSocketReceive;
            var socket = (Socket)e.UserToken;
            socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
        }

        private void OnSocketReceive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            StringReader sr = null;
            try
            {
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                sr = new StringReader(data);

                //Get  data
                if (data.Contains("Product"))
                {
                    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product));
                    var product = (Product) xs.Deserialize(sr);
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(UpdateOrder);
                }

                //Get another type of data
                if (data.Contains("Order"))
                {
                    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));
                    var order = (Order)xs.Deserialize(sr);
                    var handler = new SomeEventHandler(UpdateOrder);
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(handler, new object[]
                                                             {
                                                                 order
                                                             });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exception
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sr != null) sr.Close();
            }

            //Prepare to receive more data
            var socket = (Socket)e.UserToken;
            socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(VS.95).aspx) class in Silverlight.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(VS.95).aspx) has a good sample.