# Can I reuse my existing TCP-Server?

Tags: http, tcp, comet, server-push

At the moment I have an existing application which basically consists of a desktop GUI and a TCP server. The client connects to the server, and the server notifies the client if something interesting happens.

Now I'm supposed to replace the desktop GUI by a web GUI, and I'm wondering if I have to rewrite the server to send http packets instead of tcp packets or if I can somehow use some sort of proxy to grab the tcp packets and forward them to the web client?

Do I need some sort of comet server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make your client ask something like "Whats new pal?" to your server from time to time you can start implementing HTTP server emulator over TCP - its fun and easy process. And you could have any web based GUI.

You can just add to your TCP responds Http headers - itll probably do=)

So I mean HTTP is just a TCP with some headers like shown in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

You should probably install [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and monitor some http requests/ responses you normally do on the web and you'll get how to turn your TCP server into http emulator=)

If you want keep sockets based approche use flash (there is some  [socket api)](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/Socket.html) or silverlight (there is [socket API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225147/how-do-i-open-a-tcp-socket-from-silverlight) and you can go for NetTcpBinding or Duplexbinding something like that - it would provide you with ability to receive messages from server when server wants you to receive them (server pushes messages))

So probably you should tall us which back end you plan to use so we could recomend to you something more usefull.